# Tag: Triggers is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags

Looks like [triggers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggers) is used for both flash triggers and shutter triggers.

My recommendation would be to move shutter trigger questions to [shutter-release](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shutter-release) and then specify that [triggers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggers) is for flash triggers, but don't want to do that without sanction.

Comment: We also have [tag:remote], which might fit in somewhere....

Comment: Triggers like the PocketWizard brand can be used to trigger flashes and camera shutters.  I'm not sure if merging will help much.